# Rust return leveldb Database instance

Tags: database, rust, leveldb

I want to use the leveldb database in Rust. Everything works fine if I have all the code in one function, but I want to split the code up and have different functions for creating an entry and reading from the db. The easiest method I thought of, was to return the database instance I created in create_database and then submit it as a parameter to the function. The Problem is that Rust doesn't allow me to use Database as a type.

This works:

```rust
use std::{env, fs};
use leveldb::database::Database;
use leveldb::iterator::Iterable;
use leveldb::kv::KV;
use leveldb::options::{Options, WriteOptions, ReadOptions};


pub fn create_database() {
    let mut dir = env::current_dir().unwrap();
    dir.push("demo");

    let path_buf = dir.clone();
    fs::create_dir_all(dir).unwrap();

    let path = path_buf.as_path();
    let mut options = Options::new();
    options.create_if_missing = true;

    // Create Database
    let database = match Database::open(path, options) {
        Ok(db) => {db},
        Err(e) => {panic!("Failed to open database: {:?}", e)}
    };

    // Read from database
    let read_opts = ReadOptions::new();
    let res = database.get(read_opts, 1);
    match res {
        Ok(data) => {
            assert!(data.is_some());
            assert_eq!(data, Some(vec![1]));
        }
        Err(e) => {panic!("Failed to read from database: {:?}", e)}
    };

    let read_opts = ReadOptions::new();
    let mut iter = database.iter(read_opts);
    let entry = iter.next();
    assert_eq!(
        entry,
        Some((1, vec![1]))
    );

    // Write to database
    let write_ops = WriteOptions::new();
    match database.put(write_ops, 1, &[1]) {
        Ok(_) => {()},
        Err(e) => {panic!("Failed to write to database: {:?}", e)}
    };
}
```

But this doesn't:

```
use std::{env, fs};
use leveldb::database::Database;
use leveldb::iterator::Iterable;
use leveldb::kv::KV;
use leveldb::options::{Options, WriteOptions, ReadOptions};


pub fn create_database() -> Database {
    let mut dir = env::current_dir().unwrap();
    dir.push("demo");

    let path_buf = dir.clone();
    fs::create_dir_all(dir).unwrap();

    let path = path_buf.as_path();
    let mut options = Options::new();
    options.create_if_missing = true;

    // Create Database
    let database = match Database::open(path, options) {
        Ok(db) => {db},
        Err(e) => {panic!("Failed to open database: {:?}", e)}
    };
    return database;
}

pub fn get(database: Database) {
    // Read from database
    let read_opts = ReadOptions::new();
    let res = database.get(read_opts, 1);
    match res {
        Ok(data) => {
            assert!(data.is_some());
            assert_eq!(data, Some(vec![1]));
        }
        Err(e) => {panic!("Failed to read from database: {:?}", e)}
    };

    let read_opts = ReadOptions::new();
    let mut iter = database.iter(read_opts);
    let entry = iter.next();
    assert_eq!(
        entry,
        Some((1, vec![1]))
    );
}

pub fn put(database: Database) {
    // Write to database
    let write_ops = WriteOptions::new();
    match database.put(write_ops, 1, &[1]) {
        Ok(_) => {()},
        Err(e) => {panic!("Failed to write to database: {:?}", e)}
    };
}
```

If I execute this program I get this error:

```
error[E0107]: wrong number of type arguments: expected 1, found 0
 --> src/db/db.rs:8:29
  |
8 | pub fn create_database() -> Database {
  |                             ^^^^^^^^ expected 1 type argument

error[E0107]: wrong number of type arguments: expected 1, found 0
  --> src/db/db.rs:27:22
   |
27 | pub fn get(database: Database) {
   |                      ^^^^^^^^ expected 1 type argument

error[E0107]: wrong number of type arguments: expected 1, found 0
  --> src/db/db.rs:48:22
   |
48 | pub fn put(database: Database) {
   |                      ^^^^^^^^ expected 1 type argument

error: aborting due to 3 previous errors

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0107`.
error: could not compile `gcoin`

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
```

I have tried looking for examples to use this database but didn't find anything that matched. In the source code I found out that Database has a generic type, but couldn't find a way to fix my problem.

Comment: Looking at the [docs](http://skade.github.io/leveldb/leveldb/database/struct.Database.html), `Database` has a generic for the type for the key used. When everything was all a single function it was able to look at future calls and infer the generic type behind the scene. However, when referring to the concrete type you need to use the full type name (Which in your case looks to be `Database<i32>`).

Comment: [Database](https://docs.rs/leveldb/0.8.6/leveldb/database/struct.Database.html) is generic over its key type. You probably want `Database<i32>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! Thanks [Locke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5987669/locke) and [kmdreko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2189130/kmdreko)